# How to query multiple many to many relationships insql

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume that I have 5 tables

```
    CREATE TABLE Student
    (
        id int not null primary key auto_increment,
        firtsname varchar(30)
    );


   CREATE TABLE Lecture  
   (
       id int not null primary_key auto_increment,
       lecturename varchar(30)
   );

   CREATE TABLE Teacher
   (
       id int not null primary key auto_increment,
       name varchar(30)
   );

   CREATE TABLE StudentLecture
   (
       StudentID int,
       LectureID int,
       foreign key(StudentID) references Student(id),
       foreign key(LectureID) references Lecture(id)
   );

   CREATE TABLE TeacherLecture
   (
       TeacherID int,
       LectureID int,
       foreign key(TeacherID) references Teacher(id),
       foreign key(LectureID) references Lecture(id)
   );
```

Let's assume that I put some data into every table.
My question is is there a simple way to get in one query a result which contains Students Teachers and Lectures which are connected?
My mean is i want to get something like:
Student 'x' is assigned to 'lectureY' leading by 'teacherZ'.

Or maybe this small database is poorly designed, i am newbie, still reading and trying.

And second question is, how to make in this database properly to put the grades.
A grades should be putting by the teachers, and every student should have a list of grades for each lecture.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: simply use `JOIN`

Comment: select s.firstname,sl.LectureID,tl.LectureID from Student s join StudentLecture sl on (sl.StudentID = s.id) join TeacherLecture tl on (tl.LectureID = sl.LectureID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine.

```
select s.firstname,t.name,l.lecturename from Student s 

join StudentLecture sl on (sl.StudentID = s.id) 
join TeacherLecture tl on (tl.LectureID = sl.LectureID) 
join Teacher t on (t.id = tl.TeacherID) 
join Lecture l on (l.id = sl.LectureID)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, your tables look nice and can do the job you want, and since every lecture has students and a teacher then you may use one table `StudentLectureDetails` instead of using two; one for `StudentLecture` and one for `TeacherLecture` :

```
CREATE TABLE StudentLectureDetails
(
       LectureID int,
       TeacherID int,
       StudentID int, 
       foreign key(LectureID) references Lecture(id),
       foreign key(TeacherID) references Teacher(id),
       foreign key(StudentID) references Student(id)
);
```

Then you can retrieve the data you want directly from this table:

```
SELECT * FROM StudentLectureDetails
```

Note, this doesn't mean that your choice of the schema is wrong, it's just a matter of preference, and your choice is even better when you have to make queries related to table like `TeacherLecture` and you don't want other details to complicate your query. It also better when your data is big and you don't want to make it bigger saving redundant information in `StudentLectureDetails`. Therefore if you just keep your schema as it is now then you can use the answer mentioned by @Md Shifatul Islam to retrieve the data you want.

For the second question: you can also add students grades as another column to the same table of `StudentLectureDetails`, since it is all about the details of the students' lectures, or you can just use another table for students' lectures grades (`StudentID`, `LectureID`, `Grade`) but without mentioning the teachers.